# Limit items in a ListBox based on a previously selected option

Tags: vba, excel

How to limit field options in a list-box based on a previously selected option in Excel UserForms?

For example, we have the questions:

Do you want fruits or vegetables?

```
   - Fruit
   - Vegetable
```

Choose one:

```
   - Apple
   - Orange
   - Lettuce
   - Cucumber
```

So if they choose fruit, the next question/selection should limit the choice to only apple and orange. Apple and orange are the only choices that the user should see after choosing Fruit.

Comment: Does [this help](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)?

Comment: @BruceWayne that's not in a form control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be easier using a ComboBox instead of listbox. Get the event "on change" of fruits and vegetables and populate the other one accordingly

```
Private Sub ComboBox_FruitsVegetables_Change()
ComboBox_ChoosenFruitOrVegetable.Clear
    With ComboBox_ChoosenFruitOrVegetable
    If ComboBox_FruitsVegetables.Value = "Fruit" Then ' 1. If ComboBox_FruitsVegetables.Value = "Fruit"
    .AddItem ("my fruit") 'add items per fruit
    .Value = "my fruit"
    ElseIf ComboBox_FruitsVegetables = "Vegetables" Then ' 1. If ComboBox_FruitsVegetables.Value = "Fruit"
    .AddItem ("my veggy") 'add items per veggies
    .Value = "my veggy"
    End If ' 1. If ComboBox_FruitsVegetables.Value = "Fruit"
    End With
End Sub
```

To limit the selection to only the values you have added by VBA, go to the Properties window of the ComboBox and select Style 2.
If you have a listbox because of multiple choices allowed, let me know -which I didn't think of because the text asks "Choose one"-.

Comment: If this solved your issue, remember to check the green mark :)